# Gulp Connect not running server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I created the gulpfile.js and in it has a use for gulp-connect

```
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: 'dev',
        livereload: true,
        port: 8000
    });
})
```

When I run `gulp connect` it does not maintain my server on `localhost:8000`.

```
[14:08:51] Starting 'connect'...
[14:08:51] Server started http://localhost:8000
[14:08:51] LiveReload started on port 35729
[14:08:51] Finished 'connect' after 13 ms
```

Hence I get nothing when opening up `http://locahost:8000`

What can I do to make connect work and create a server to deploy my html?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by having more than one file in the served folder (my dist directory). I don't know why it works but it started working after that.

I used the following settings:

```
gulp.task('connect', function(){
connect.server({
    root: ['dist'],
    port: 8000,
    base: 'http://localhost',
    livereload: true
});
```

I use v2.2.0 of gulp-connect.

Answer (score 1):

gulp-connect has been deprecated.

You may wish to use the rewritten package called [gulp-webserver](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver).

Comment: Where did you get that is deprecated?

Comment: There was a deprecation warning as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/67) at the time this question was asked. The gulp-webserver package had no such issues. As far as I'm aware the deprecation warning is no longer a problem and either package should work fine.

Comment: @RustyFluff I think your reading of the issue and deprecation is incorrect. I believe the issue to remove a warning when gulp-connect.